# How to add parameter dynamically to url in Angular Service

Tags: angular, typescript, url, service, pagination

I am trying to do pagination, retrieving data from oracle database and display 20 rows per page.Here is my Angular service:

```
 pastHourInfo() {
        const url='/Search-Service/users/transaction';
        return this.http.get(url).pipe(map((data:any)=>data));
    }
```

I want to add one parameter to the url above.When I click on specific page, for example on page 2, I want to add respective number :  /Search-Service/users/transaction/2 and so on.
How can I do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This ?

```
pastHourInfo(page = 0) {
    const url='/Search-Service/users/transaction';
    return this.http.get(`${url}/${page}`).pipe(map((data:any)=>data));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            **you just pass the number as a parameter**  

           pastHourInfo(2) {
               const url='/Search-Service/users/transaction/' + 2;
                return this.http.get(url).pipe(map((data:any)=>data));
                 }
```

Comment: How to retrieve on which page I clicked as a parameter?

Comment: are you retrieving whole page data or  clicked page data?

Comment: when I click on page 1 , I want to retrieve from databases datas of 1-20 rows, when I click on page 2 - datas of 20-40 rows and e.t.c

Answer (score -1):

For this to work you will need to 
Create one API with `HTTP POST` request type. and in that you can give things like page size, sorting order etc...